# Check for collision between a circle and the perimeter of a circle sector

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to create a function that checks if there is a collision/intersection between a circle and the perimeter of a circle sector.

I'm going to explain my problem in more detail:
1. I have a circle sector defined by the center point(x1,y1), the radius(r1) and the angle(m) that tells me where the circle sector starts and ends.
2. On the other hand, I have a circle defined by the center point (x2,y2), the radius(r2).
3. I'm creating a small game in HTML5 canvas in which both of these geometric shapes can move freely.
4. The problem is that I wanna know if these two (the green circle sector and the green circle) are colliding to each other.

[image]

My current code is very basic (as I can't come up of something that can efficiently check collision). It only checks the collision between the circle that defines that circle sector and the other circle:

```
this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
    // "this" is the circle
    // "otherobj" is the circle sector
    var dx = this.x - otherobj.x;
    var dy = this.y - otherobj.y;
    var distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    var crash = false;
    if (distance < this.radius +otherobj.radius) {
        crash = true;
    }
    return crash;
}
```

Note: The circle sector (in color green) has a line width (as seen in the image) and the angle m changes (because the circle sector is spinning around the center).

I think the proper solution would be something that can can calculate collisions knowing that the circle sector shape doesn't change (it is only spinning).

Comment: You need to include the angles in your condition

Comment: All the variables I mentioned is given. You can use a bigger or smaller angle, but you need to make sure that you can generate a circle sector.

Comment: Right now, I am using (x1,y1) = (240,240), r1 = 120 and m=0.6radians for circle sector and (x2,y2)=(240,440), r2=20 for circle. Remember (x1,y1), (x2,y2) and m changes when the circle and the circle sector is moving/spinning.

Comment: Not sure I follow... on your condition `if (distance < this.radius +otherobj.radius)` you are not including angles, you must calculate the angle from the centers of your circles

Comment: Exactly, its only calculating the intersection between circle and the other circle that defines the circle sector. That's my current approximation for the solution.

Comment: so you need to include the angles in that condition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182512/discussion-between-helder-sepulveda-and-00mugen00).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a clear understanding of geometry...
You are already using Pythagoras to determine if the circles collide.

To detect head on collisions you need to include the angles in your condition, see image below:

[image]

When angle `c` is greater than `a` and less than `b` you got yourself a head on collision.

Next will be to figure out side collisions

Comment: This is not sufficient.  For angles C that are only slightly smaller than A, there could still be a collision, assuming the circle has a non-zero radius.

Comment: @Beska not sure I see that.. can you put it in an image

Comment: However, if you add a second check that calculates the endpoints of the arc and determines if they are within the area of the small circle, and also count those as a collision, that may be sufficent...I think...

Comment: here is my drawing if it helps as a starting point: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1QvpqGJdDL2pn5Y53ltxz7kI6_1jks9IZpUhn2opoq80/edit

Comment: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1jk0pZM4ZObdB4OZnGOhPhhlUXIz1iBhW3gbfYrTb99w/edit

The center of the small circle is outside the angle of the arc...but because the circle isn't just a point, it still intersects with the endpoint of the arc.  I suspect adding the endpoint checks I mentioned may take care of the issue, though there could still be an edge case I'm not thinking of.

Comment: @Beska that link is not accessible to all ... but I think I see your point, I was only thinking on a heads on collision but there could be a side collision as wellI added a blue circle to mine showing another possibility

Comment: Yep.  That's it exactly.

Comment: It think it's not just that easy as you think. It depends on whether the smaller circle may be in the larger circle. If not, it's okay to just check the angle but if it is allowed to enter the larger one you have to check if some point of the smaller circle touches the segments perimeter. Any point of the left or right semicircle may touch the perimeter.

Comment: @Beska I updated my answer to reflect this covers only head on collisions

Comment: I think the easiest thing would be to calculate the intersection points. If any point has a greater angle than a or smaller angle than b you have a collision. But that works only with permeters without a width.

Comment: @Sebi2020 Do you mind elaborating on the calculation of the intersection points ... that could very well be the solution, mine was the case when there was only one intersection point as is the case on head-on collisions

Comment: @HelderSepulveda https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256100/how-can-i-find-the-points-at-which-two-circles-intersect
Just that and then you only have to do a little bit of Trigonometry with the x and y coordinates to get the angle.